# Help writing a regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

I asked a very similar question to this one almost a month ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5119050/help-parsing-a-string-potentially-using-regular-expressions).

I am trying very hard to understand regular expressions, but not a bit of it makes any sense.  SLak's solution in that question worked well, but when I try to use the Regex Helper at http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ it only matches the first comma of `-2.2,1.1-6.9,2.3-12.8,2.3` when given the regex `,|(?<!^|,)(?=-)`

In other words I can't find a single regex tool that will even help me understand it.  Well, enough whining.  I'm now trying to re-write this regex so that I can do a Regex.Split() to split up the string `2.2 1.1-6.9,2.3-12.8 2.3` into `-2.2`, `1.1`, `-6.9`, `2.3`, `-12.8`, and `2.3`.

The difference the aforementioned question is that there can now be leading and/or trailing whitespace, and that whitespace can act as a delimiter as can a comma.

I tried using `\s|,|(?<!^|,)(?=-)` but this doesn't work.  I tried using this to split `293.46701,72.238185`, but C# just tells me "the input string was not in a correct format".  Please note that there is leading and trailing whitespace that SO does not display correctly.

EDIT: Here is the code which is executed, and the variables and values after execution of the code.
[image]

Comment: Can you post your code (not just the regular expression, but also the way you are using it) and show which line gives the error.

Comment: @Mark - Done.  You can see that it is not splitting correctly.

Comment: Will there ever be floats in scientific notation? (possibly having exponents having optional sign?) i.e. `+1.2E-23`

Answer (score 5):

If it doesn't have to be Regex, and if it doesn't have to be slow :-) this should do it for you:

```
var components = "2.2 1.1-6.9,2.3-12.8 2.3".Replace("-", ",-").
Split(new[]{' ', ','},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Components would then contain:[2.2 1.1 -6.9 2.3 -12.8 2.3]

Comment: +1 seems like a great solution for someone that is having a hard time with regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Does it need to be split?  You could do `Regex.Matches(text, @"\-?[\d]+(\.[\d]+)?")`.

If you need split, `Regex.Split(text, @"[^\d.-]+|(?=-)")` should work also.

P.S. I used Regex Hero to test on the fly http://regexhero.net

Comment: Or you could use Regex.Split(",")... or for that matter String.Split(",").

Comment: It makes no difference for the results, but consider using `?` instead of `{0,1}`.

Comment: I like `{0,1}` because it looks more complicated.  :]]  j/k, you're right.  I've edited the answer.

Comment: Actually, Matches works perfectly!  Now I just have to figure out how to extract those matches into an array of doubles.

Comment: Pretty simple with Linq: `Regex.Matches(text, @"\-?[\d]+(\.[\d]+)?").Cast<Match>().Select(x=>Convert.ToDouble(x.Value)).ToArray()`

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing the point entirely (it's Sunday night and I'm tired ;) ) I think you need to concentrate more on matching the things you ***do*** want and not the things you *don't* want.

```
Regex argsep = new Regex(@"\-?[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*");
string text_to_split = "-2.2 1.1-6.9,2.3-12.8 2.3 293.46701,72.238185";
var tmp3 = argsep.Matches(text_to_split);
```

This gives you a `MatchCollection` of each of the values you wanted.

To break that down and try and give you an understanding of what it's saying, split it up into parts:

`\-?` Matches a literal minus sign (\ denotes literal characters) zero or one time (?)
`[0-9]+` Matches any character from 0 to 9, one or more times (+)
`\.?` Matches a literal full stop, zero or one time (?)
`[0-9]*` Matches any character from 0 to 9 again, but this time it's zero or more times (*)

You don't need to worry about things like \s (spaces) for this regex, as the things you're actually trying to match are the positive/negative numbers.

Comment: If you look at the very first string in the OP's question, it does say `-2.2`, he must have copied it wrong the second time.

Comment: Ah yes, so it does! It definitely *is* Sunday night and I definitely *am* tired ;) Regex still works regardless though, so not all bad :)

Comment: Yep yep, no worries. If I were to use regex to solve this it would look pretty darn close to yours.

Comment: It has a couple of minor problems. `4711.` is matched as a number and `.4711` is matched as `4711`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4246077/simple-problem-with-regular-expression-only-digits-and-commas/4247184#4247184 makes me think that it's probably better to split than to try to match numbers.

Comment: Haha! Good point, well made. That reference is a pedant's delight! It could be argued that 4711. should be matched as a number (double.Parse() will parse it as 4711.0).  .4711 shouldn't be matched as 4711 though, which is the case for Andy's one too. The OP gave a few examples and both regexes match the provided examples though.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the string split function. String operations are way faster than regular expressions and much simpler to use/understand.

Comment: Take a look at rasmusvhansens answer :)

Answer (score 0):

If the "Matches" approach doesnt work you could perhaps hack something in two steps?

```
Regex RE = new Regex(@"(-?[\d.]+)|,|\s+");
RE.Split(" -2.2,1.1-6.9,2.3-12.8,2.3 ")
       .Where(s=>!string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
```

Outputs:

```
-2.2
1.1
-6.9
2.3
-12.8
2.3
```